# Error Building JCEF: how to fix Module Not Found?

Tags: java, javafx, chromium-embedded

I am trying to build the most recent version of JCEF from their official website to use in a JavaFX Application.

I am running this command: `cmake -G "Visual Studio 16" -A x64 ..`

The following is the error I am getting (full log with error at the bootom):

```
PS D:\IntelliJ\ppacoursework4\libs\jcef2\jcef_build> cmake -G "Visual Studio 16" -A x64 ..
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.22635.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30154.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30154.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:190 (find_package):
  Policy CMP0148 is not set: The FindPythonInterp and FindPythonLibs modules
  are removed.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0148" for policy details.  Use
  the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Found PythonInterp: C:/Users/enzob/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe (found version "3.12.2")
-- Using Python: C:/Users/enzob/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe
-- Found JNI: D:/Program Files/Java/jdk-21/include (Required is at least version "1.7") found components: AWT JVM
-- Generating native/jcef_version.h file...
File native/jcef_version.h is already up to date.
-- Downloading clang-format from Google Storage...
Failed to fetch file gs://chromium-clang-format/66882fadbf9e99cc00b8677d8c1e7e8b3cfdf4fe for tools/buildtools/win/clang-format.exe. [Err: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\IntelliJ\ppacoursework4\libs\jcef2\tools\buildtools\external_bin\gsutil\gsutil_4.68\gsutil\gsutil", line 21, in <module>
    gsutil.RunMain()
  File "D:\IntelliJ\ppacoursework4\libs\jcef2\tools\buildtools\external_bin\gsutil\gsutil_4.68\gsutil\gsutil.py", line 121, in RunMain
    import gslib.__main__
  File "D:\IntelliJ\ppacoursework4\libs\jcef2\tools\buildtools\external_bin\gsutil\gsutil_4.68\gsutil\gslib\__main__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from six.moves import configparser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six.moves'
]
0> Downloading tools/buildtools/win/clang-format.exe@66882fadbf9e99cc00b8677d8c1e7e8b3cfdf4fe...
0> Failed to fetch file gs://chromium-clang-format/66882fadbf9e99cc00b8677d8c1e7e8b3cfdf4fe for tools/buildtools/win/clang-format.exe, skipping. [Err: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\IntelliJ\ppacoursework4\libs\jcef2\tools\buildtools\external_bin\gsutil\gsutil_4.68\gsutil\gsutil", line 21, in <module>
    gsutil.RunMain()
  File "D:\IntelliJ\ppacoursework4\libs\jcef2\tools\buildtools\external_bin\gsutil\gsutil_4.68\gsutil\gsutil.py", line 121, in RunMain
    import gslib.__main__
  File "D:\IntelliJ\ppacoursework4\libs\jcef2\tools\buildtools\external_bin\gsutil\gsutil_4.68\gsutil\gslib\__main__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from six.moves import configparser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six.moves'
]
Downloading 1 files took 0.169491 second(s)
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:296 (message):
  Execution failed with unexpected result: 1


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Has anyone ever seen something like this before? Any ideas on how to solve this issue are welcome.

Thanks!

"Solutions" I have already attempted: `pip unistall six` followed by `pip install six`

Comment: Do you have to build chromium embedded yourself, or can you [download a prebuilt binary](https://github.com/jcefmaven/jcefbuild/releases), or use the JavaFX built-in [`WebView`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/)instead?